# How to test heteroskedasticity at the independent variable level?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, heteroscedasticity

I know how to test the heteroskedasticity of a model's residuals.  I am inquiring about how to test for heteroskedasticity for each specific independent variables included in the model.  What is the best test for that?

Comment: This added info under my question does not stick.  So, I am duplicating it here.  I know how to test the heteroskedasticity of a model's residuals.  I am inquiring about how to test for heteroskedasticity for each specific independent variables included in the model.  What is the best test for that?

Comment: What method would you use in the case of residuals, and why would that not apply for a predictor?

Comment: Breush-Pagan and/or the White Test.  Their respective structure, I think, are not workable for testing the independent variables vs testing the overall model.  I uncovered that the Park test is appropriate to test independent variable on this count.  But, I think there is some reservations regarding this test.  There may be some reservations in testing heteroskedasticity at the variable level, I don't know.  Any insight on the issue is welcome.

Comment: Why couldn't Levene's test be used?

Comment: The Levene's test is appropriate for hypothesis testing to test the difference between two groups Averages.  I don't think it is the most appropriate test for testing heteroskedasticity of residuals for the overall regression or relative to specific independent variables.  The latter is really my question.